# Identify 3D scan technolgoy

Tags: scanning

I'm curious what is the technology category for this 3D scanner device:

Does the device fit into any technology category [listed by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_scanning#Technology)?

Could it be [structured light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured-light_3D_scanner) approach?

Answer (score 1):

That's not Structured light, it is a camera. The camera makes a series of photos - one with each flash. Then, the photos are stitched to create a 3D model using a code that is similar to one I was shown in an informatics class in my uni once:

- the software identifies structures that are identical.
- By tracking the difference between the pictures, distances away from the camera between the different photos are estimated. As a result, several passes in different angles give us a complete 3D scan.
- Motion of the scanner probably is included in the metadata, allowing to calculate the angles more precisely.

So, it's **[Photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry)**.

Comment: I didn't expect Photogrammetry!

Comment: High quality Photogrammetry requires lots of images. So, the camera should be taking a **large** series of photos, right?

Comment: Photo and video it seems. Each flash is a reference picture for the video.

Comment: Just as a possibility, could the device be combining Photogrammetry with some other approaches to increase quality?